# composer multiple authentication for a single repo

Tags: authentication, composer-php

Is it possible to have multiple authentications for a single repo?
In my Magento 2 project, I used modules that were purchased using my Magento account. My client has modules that were purchased in his Magento account which need to install in the said project.

I want to use 2 authentication credentials in repo.magento.com when composer tries to install and search packages. Is this possible? If so, please let me know how to do it.

Comment: Just to be sure: you want to run a project for your client using modules the client has not purchased?

Comment: Yes that's right. Basically I will be using modules that I personally purchased through my Magento marketplace account and modules that the client purchased through his/her Magento marketplace account.

Comment: Is this covered in legal terms? In our agency's projects, we have to ensure that all licenses are provided by the customer